# Socket.io keeps polling to establish connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a messaging application working with Socket.io.

Currently we're facing an issue with setting up our application with a reverse proxy in the middle. When we run our application locally then we've got no problem but when putting the reverse proxy in between it keeps on socket.io keeps on polling. So it's  constantly polling and no data is flowing through the long-polling connection.

Has anyone faced this before? What type of configurations have we missed?

Edit 1:

This is a screenshot from the socket io client logger
[image: socket io client logger]

This is a screenshot from the network tab where it keeps polling:

[image: network tab]

Edit 2:

We use socket.io in `polling` transport mode only. So we don't try to setup a real websocket connection.

Comment: What are you using for your reverse proxy? You've probably already tried this but here's a tutorial on config of socket.io with nginx: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Comment: We're using Akamai. Akamai routes traffic from domainA to our server domain.

Comment: we'd beable to help more with code

Comment: Not sure what I'm looking at since I've never used Akamai but this seems like it might be something that could help you: https://community.akamai.com/docs/DOC-8637-websocket-support

Comment: Thank you! So we no that Akamai doesn't support websocket connections without a special upgrade. So it only works via the `polling` transport. 

The weird thing is that when we've got a default rule in Akamai saying to route all unmatched traffic to our domain to our server then it works with polling. But when we disable this rule then it doesn't work anymore... and we get into this loop of polling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it had to do with caching of the socket.io requests in Akamai. In the routing rules an explicit no cache behaviour needed to be declared.